# Disable pinch-in to dismiss gesture in QLPreviewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to disable pinch-in gesture to dismiss gesture in QLPreviewController when present it. if I push the QLPreviewController everything work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you present the `QLPreviewController` inside a `UINavigationController`, the zoom to dismiss gesture is automatically disabled. The look-and-feel otherwise is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. Wasted a lot of hours trying to disable this behavior.